# How to make a hold to click autoclicker?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This autoclicker script I found automatically clicks the mouse when you press the "s" key. However, I want to change it so that the autoclicker will only run when the left mouse button is depressed. I have spent a surplus of 10 hours trying to figure this one out, but frankly, I'm terrible at coding. Any help would be great. (Also, there is no GetKeyState or GetASyncKeyState in any library I know of)

My code is:

```
import threading
from pynput.mouse import Button, Controller
from pynput.keyboard import Listener, KeyCode


delay = 0.01
button = Button.left
start_stop_key = KeyCode(char='s')
exit_key = KeyCode(char='e')


class ClickMouse(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, delay, button):
        super(ClickMouse, self).__init__()
        self.delay = delay
        self.button = button
        self.running = False
        self.program_running = True

    def start_clicking(self):
        self.running = True

    def stop_clicking(self):
        self.running = False

    def exit(self):
        self.stop_clicking()
        self.program_running = False

    def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)


mouse = Controller()
click_thread = ClickMouse(delay, button)
click_thread.start()


def on_press(key):
    if key == start_stop_key:
        if click_thread.running:
            click_thread.stop_clicking()
        else:
            click_thread.start_clicking()
    elif key == exit_key:
        click_thread.exit()
        listener.stop()


with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Which part specifically are you struggling with? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Comment: It's a bit confusing what you're asking for. A mouse "click" or "press" is holding the mouse down, followed by releasing it. But you want this to happen when the mouse is already held down?

Comment: Basically, I want the loop to only run when the mouse button is held down.
``` def run(self):
        while self.program_running:
            while self.running:
                mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to microsoft to get the Virtual-Key codes for input.

For left mouse buttons, the code is 0x01. for Right mouse buttons the code is 0x02.

You will also need to install pywin32 and import the win32 api

Then you can do something like this:

````
```while True:
    a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x01)
    print(a)
    time.sleep(255.0)  #this should be long enough
````

Basically, when this is run where there's no input pressed, the script will print 0 indefinitely.  However when it is pressed, it will print a 1 for as long as it's pressed.
From there you can make that into an if/then statement and activate the clicking function.